# Fix Regular Expression for Emails to Not allow Consecutive Periods

Tags: javascript, regex, validation

my regular Expressions are pretty bad so I thought  would look for some help on this.

I have a regular expression:

```
/[a-z0-9!#$%&'*+/=?^_`{|}~-]+(?:\.[a-z0-9!#$%&'*+/=?^_`{|}~-]+)*@(?:[a-z0-9](?:[a-z0-9-]*[a-z0-9])?\.)+[a-z0-9](?:[a-z0-9-]*[a-z0-9])?/;
```

and it works for most cases of my email validation however it allows this one through:

test..testing@gmail.com

How would I alter the above Regular Expression to not allow consecutive periods anywhere throughout the string?

Thanks.

Comment: But that's a perfectly valid email address.

Comment: Part of a functional spec that was approved. No consecutive periods.

Comment: It's part of your job as a technology professional to make sure that people providing you with requirements don't accidentally design an error into the product they're paying you to work on.

Comment: @Seth: Then you need to show us your spec. You are not validating email addresses, but instead some subset of email addresses that your manager has concocted. Or better yet, slap your manager upside the head for being a complete moron (or gently point out the error!).

Comment: Think of it this way: what error message will you show the person who has typed in their valid email address, one which happens to have two consecutive periods in it?  "Invalid email address", when the user knows full well that it's not "invalid"?

Comment: Whoa - hey everybody while I think the overall spirit of this is right-headed, @markijbema points out in a comment that strict RFC5322 addresses can't actually have successive dots in the left-hand part of an address ...

Comment: (I think the criticism is valid in spirit because there are other address forms that the regex does not accept, for whatever that's worth.)

Comment: @Tomalak: How about RFC 2822, section 3.2.3 and 3.2.4?

Comment: @Pointy it is, that's why one should either write a regex for an email, based directly on the RFC (and for most purposes, one can safely ignore the whitespace/comment directives, and it is really not that complicated), or take an existing expression which has been proved.

Comment: Actually @markijbema it drives me nuts when sites don't accept `"My Real Name" <whatever@someplace.com>` as an address, because it's useful.

Comment: In any case @markijbema thank you for introducing some reality here :-)

Comment: I agree and believe me I have pointed out email addresses that are valid however won't work with their FS, however the management team has explained that those email addresses are restricted in their Terms of Service. While I don't know how ethical that is, it is what it is and therefore I'm creating a solution to target their specifics. I approve of the criticism, it's what makes us better. Thank you for all the comments everyone.

Comment: @Seth Duncan - sounds like you're doing everything you can. What's the world to do with people who just don't "get" the Internet?

Comment: @markijbema: See comments on my answer. Following the RFC strictly, whilst theoretically "correct", is useless in the real world _especially_ for email addresses.

Comment: Interestingly enough, GMail does not allow you to create an account with consecutive periods.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

To avoid matching two consecutive dots you can add a negative lookahead at the beginning of your regular expression:

```
/^(?!.*\.{2})[a-z0-9etc...
 ------------
```

It will fail to match if there are two consecutive periods anywhere in the string and it doesn't require any other modifications to your original regular expression.

However it seems a bad idea as your regular expression isn't correct in the first place. If you insist on using regular expressions to validate email addresses, try this:

- [Mail::RFC822::Address: regexp-based address validation](http://www.ex-parrot.com/~pdw/Mail-RFC822-Address.html)

Comment: "Add this to your regular expression. It doesn't require any modifications to your regular expression." Nice

Comment: But it will still allow for the dot directly before the @ (and of course you can fix that as well, but where's the end?)

Comment: @markijbema: The end is to do it properly. See the link I've added in my update.

Comment: Besides the ethical dilemma of not accepting some users email address, the idea was to fulfill the FS and this is what I was asking for. Thank you.

Comment: Just to note here again that strictly following the RFC is all well and good in theory, but often fails in practice. Sad but true. Your regex will reject active and functioning email addresses, and there is little more frustrating!

Comment: I disagree that the RFC fails in practice. People can fail by registering invalid email addresses and then they can get frustrated when they don't work properly, but it's their own fault (or else their service provider's fault for giving them an invalid email address). The RFC is a pain, but life without the RFC would be even worse. Best just to stick to the RFC when registering an email address, and for those that chose to ignore this advice and  registered and are actively using invalid email addresses - good luck with that!

Answer (score 5):

Don't. That email address is [functional in practice](http://www.regular-expressions.info/email.html) (albeit [technically invalid](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2822#section-3.4.1) according to the relevant RFC).

Top tip: do not "validate" email addresses with regex as you will get it wrong.

Comment: Nop, it isn't, you cannot have consecutive dots. And the adress is not allowed to start with a dot, or end with a dot.

Comment: @markijbema: RFC822 fails it, but in the real world, I can make you a functional email address with consecutive dots. This is why validators are doomed to failure in practice.

Comment: Wow, you're right, that actually works. Don't go around claiming it's *valid* though, that's just plain confusing. But i've retracted my -1, and converted it to a +1.

Comment: @markijbema: Fair enough; "valid" might be a confusing term here.

Answer (score 1):

`// Valid - email Regex`
`^[A-Za-z0-9_%+-]+(?:\.[A-Za-z0-9_%+-]+)*@[A-Za-z0-9.-]+\.[A-Za-z]{2,}$`

Use this one, this will not allow any email to start and end with period, as well as no consecutive periods and special symbols

Answer (score 0):

Don't try to invent the wheel ;)

For instance, see here:

http://www.regular-expressions.info/email.html